# Put Hashtag in parameter's value

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to redirect user when he log in.

In my website, you can log in from different places (on the main menu, on some pages, etc.) so I want that after the user is log in, he ll be redirect to the page he was before.

I got a long code for that process, but the problem is in the log in panel.

This is the a part of code that make the problem, for exemple if I have "**index.php#page=games**" the page user must be redirect to, after log in :

My code

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="login_redirect" name="login_redirect" value="index.php#page=games" />
```

JAVASCRIPT / AJAX

```
var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&login_redirect=' + login_redirect;

    //send informations 
    $("#message_login").load("php_login_code.php?"+dataString);
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $login_redirect = $_GET['login_redirect'];
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location = <?php echo $login_redirect; ?>; //redirect to game's page
                        location.reload();
                    </script>
```

The problem is : I only get this link : **index.php**

And I should get this link **index.php#page=games**

**EDIT**

I think the problem come from the Ajax script, the hashtag can't be send as value of parameter. How could I get out off this ?

Comment: what about if you store the redirect URL as a session?

Comment: well I will try, it seems to be legit.

Comment: @tonoslfx doesn't work

Comment: what about if you add extra parameter? add one more hidden field for the hash tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [`encodeURICompoent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on any data that you insert into a URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php#page=games
```

A hash in a URL usually means to anchor to a certain title, for example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Automatic_memory_management
```

What you should be doing is just removing the `#` alltogether, and just use a query string. Much simpler, and much more straight forward.

```
index.php?page=games

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $login_redirect = $_GET['page'];
}
```

If you're trying to get values from the HTML DOM, you want to `post` the data, instead of sending a `get` request.

Comment: I know that, the thing is I have 70% javascript website, in one page "index.php" (with a lot of includes), so If I use "?" I must reload the page, But my webiste almost never refresh, it's 70% javascript and animated, transition, etc.

Comment: Okay; well then can't you make the same request, but from AJAX? and have PHP echo back whatever value you want?

Comment: Easier != better. Have a look at AJAX. It's the best way to communicate with the server, without a single page refresh :)